# CUDA with map<value, key> & atomic operations

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, cuda

As far as I know I can use C++ templates in CUDA device code. So If i'm using map to create a dictionary will the operation of inserting new values be atomic?

I want to count the number of appearances of a certain values, i.e. create a code-dictionary with probabilities of the codes.

Thanks

Macs

Comment: I'm pretty sure CUDA uses its own C variant with instristics. No templates, then.

Comment: But http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=98087 states, that "You can use templates in device code"

Comment: @macs: That's my new learned thing for the day, then. :) Whether or not those operations will be atomic depends on the implementation, I think, so you'd have to find a resource on the guarantees nVidia makes.

Comment: @GMan: Well, i'll give it a try then and will let you know about the results :D

Comment: @GMan you can use templates and inheritance.I know for sure because I do use them successfully

Comment: @GMan: Since you have many hundreds of threads executing simultaneously, and read-modify-write operation is subject to races. To get a truly atomic operation on any given variable you should use the atomic intrinsics (e.g. atomicAdd()) as described in the Programming Guide (link below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use STL within device code. You could check [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) for similar functionality (check the experimental namespace in particular).

Templates are fine in device code, CUDA C currently supports quite a few C++ features although some of the big ones such as virtual functions and exceptions are not yet possible ( and will only be possible on Fermi hardware).

If you decide to implement this yourself, you can use the atomicAdd() intrinsic to get an atomic operation, check out the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_ProgrammingGuide_3.0.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Is it just the allocators that make STL not compatible with CUDA?  If we were to write our own allocators, could we use STL in CUDA?

Comment: That is, what i wanted to know ... learned another lection: Next time i'll give the cue STL.

Comment: I have found nothing in Thrust that offers functionality comparable to `std::map`. I've seen nothing that would allow a dictionary-like lookup, such as `int value = myMap["key"]`.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, you are trying to use STL map inside cuda?
most likely it is not going to work. You will have to devise your own implementation.
You may be able to find implementation in thrust library however.